# What does Hinduism say about keeping the photo of a deceased child (who was a young adult)

Tags: death

What does Hinduism say about keeping the photo of a deceased child who was a young adult at the time?

Can his/her portrait be kept in the living room surrounded with garland?

Comment: Customs vary from place to place. Take note that shraadham is not performed for a person who died prematurely. Also, children are usually buried and not cremated. I don't think keeping a portrait in the living room is common, though it need not be disallowed.

Comment: Any deceased family member is part of Pitras(ancestors) and their photo should be hanged in South-West region of House and south or west wall facing north or east, according to the Vastu Shastra. Don't hang the photo of Pitras in the bedroom or near house temple.